# I want to load external html file into main div when i click on navigation links without page refresh. But I don't know how

Tags: jquery

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Responsive Side Menu</h1>
    </div>
```

This code is of index.html and is similar for other pages

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery (a JavaScript library) you can utilize the load() function to load the contents of another HTML file on your server and place it anywhere you want on the current page without refreshing (so you can even replace the current HTML if you like).

jQuery:
http://jquery.com/

jQuery load():
http://api.jquery.com/load/